# jquery not working in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first time trying to work with JQuery and i am trying to deconstruct a piece of code i found online. It works in jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xeyaaqte/). However, when i try to run the code in a browser, the part that is supposed to work when "create an account" is clicked, does not display. I have modified the code to work with the browser and it is as follows:

My index.html file:

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="login-page">
 <div class="form">
   <form class="register-form">
     <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
     <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
     <button>create</button>
     <p id="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
   </form>
   <form class="login-form">
     <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
     <button>login</button>
     <p id="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a> </p>
   </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

My script.js file:

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

All the files are in the same directory. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: `It works in jsfiddle. However, when i try to run the code in a browser` - what? jsfiddle runs in the browser

Comment: does this required jQuery UI ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @JaromandaX what I meant is when i run the index.html in the browser

Comment: yes, either way, it's in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the Javascript in the header, before the document has been fully parsed, so the handler you're adding isn't attaching to anything. Either give the script the `defer` attribute to force it to load once everything's been parsed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

or put the script at the very bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Basically what Certain means by "fully parsed" is that you're attempting to add an event handler to an element when you load your `script.js` file before the element has been created. Normally, this would spit out an error in your console, but jQuery handle these errors so you don't see anything.

Comment: It's not so much that jQuery handles the errors, but that it's the equivalent of `document.querySelectorAll('.message a').forEach(a => ...` - which would produce no errors in vanilla JS as well - there are just no items to iterate over.

Comment: Weird, I've had errors thrown at me before when I did it manually. Maybe it was browser specific that I did something to it without noticing.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, weirdly, neither of those approaches worked.

Comment: @kenny, what happens? Are you sure the script runs with no errors? Is jQuery defined properly when the script runs?

Comment: @CertainPerformance after trying it again, I realise that it does work. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this, it will work. I modify your code on jsfiddle, check https://jsfiddle.net/xeyaaqte/7

```
$(function () {
    $('.message a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test")
        $('form').animate({ height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle" }, "slow");
    });
});
```